# When packaging springboot as JAR, the ServletContextEvent.getServletContext returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

This is my code implementing the CommandLineRunner and ServletContextListener,
When springboot starts I want to get the ServletContext and put the data to it.
In the normal case which means not packaging to jar just start the springboot in Idea IDE is OK, but when I packaging it to the jar the, the sce.getServletContext() will return the NUll for me. how to solve this problem?
Thanks.

```
@Order(10)
@Component("startupRunner")
public class StartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner, ServletContextListener {

    private ServletContext application = null;

    @Resource
    private FilmService filmService;

    @Resource
    private WebSiteInfoService webSiteInfoService;

    @Resource
    private LinkService linkService;

    @Autowired
    private WebSiteService webSiteService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.loadData();
    }


    public void loadData() {
        System.out.println("vincent.applicaiton" + application);
        application.setAttribute("newestInfoList", webSiteInfoService.list(null, 0, 10));
        Film film = new Film();
        film.setHot(1);
        application.setAttribute("newestHotFilmList", filmService.list(film, 0, 10));
        application.setAttribute("newestIndexHotFilmList", filmService.list(film, 0, 32));
        application.setAttribute("newestWebSiteList", webSiteService.newestList(0, 10));
        application.setAttribute("newestFilmList", filmService.list(null, 0, 10);
        application.setAttribute("linkList", linkService.listAll());
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //WebApplicationContext requiredWebApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sce.getServletContext());
        //application= requiredWebApplicationContext.getServletContext();
        application = sce.getServletContext();

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a stupid method to solve this problem, which is

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    if (application != null)
        this.loadData();
}
```

when using mevan packaging the springboot I do the verify, this action can avoid the null point exception. anyone has more elegant solution?